# Cкрипт, открывающий сайт без видимой ссылки

Tags: скрипт, javascript, dle, ucoz

История такова: имею 2 сайта, один на Ucoz, второй на DLE. Первый был юкоз, не плохо разросся 1.5 года. Но юкоз отстой, сделал сайт на DLE и не хочу сильно морочиться с раскруткой и думаю на ucoz сделать такую вещь.

Если юзер зашел на сайт, он ничего не делает и закрывает вкладку, то ничего не происходит. Но если юзер кликнул по любой точке сайта (вообще по любой) даже туда, где нету ссылки, то у него открывается мой сайт на DLE в новой вкладке, но при этом он должен остатся на ucoz сайте. И после того, как у него открылся сайт, он больше не открывается. В куки походу как-то...

Думаю, все правильно и понятно выразил))

PS: видел такое на каком-то сайте...

Comment: > имею 2 сайта, один на Ucoz, второй на DLE.

Дальше читать не стал :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> видел такое на каком-то сайте...

На любом сайте с рекламой во всплывающих окнах.

```
var DLE = false;
document.body.onClick = function(){
    if(!DLE){
        window.open('_URL_');
        DLE = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: И именно из-за тех, кто написал этот скрипт, я ненавижу интернет.